# increment a variable based on loop count

Tags: php, loops, foreach, language-construct

I have a PHP function where an undefined number of images in a directory are being output to the browser.  The images are being read in to an object.  The issue I'm having is how the images are presented.  I want to put them in a table, four `<td>` cells in a row.  Here is the code:

```
function displayThumbList(){

   $tlist = $this->getThumbList();
   $i = 0;
   $e = 3;
   echo '<table width="400px" border=1><tr>';
   foreach ($tlist as $value) {
    echo "<td width=\"90px\" height=\"50px\"><a href=\"showImage.php?id=".$this->getBaseName($value,$this->thumbPrefix)."\" target=\"imgHolder\"><img class=\"timg\" src=\"thumbnail/".$value."\" alt=\"a\" /></a></td>";
    $_GET['imagefocus'] = $this->getBaseName($value,$this->thumbPrefix);

  //here is where the condition for adding a <tr> tag is evaluated 
  if ($i == $e){
       echo '<tr>';
     }

  $i++; //increments by 1 with each foreach loop
 }
 echo '</table>';
}
```

The first time $i(third time through foreach loop) is equal to $e, the process adds the  as expected. I need $e to increment by 3 AFTER each time the condition is met.

The number of images are undefined. If there are 21 images in the directory, $i would increment 21 times and $e should increment 7 times adding 3 with each increment (3,6,9,12,15 etc).

I guess I'm looking for an increment based on another loop condition (every time equality is reached).  Any thoughts?
rwhite35

Comment: Just add `$e += 3` in the block controlled by the `if ($i == $e)` statement.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the **modulo** operator? It's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($i == $e){
   echo '<tr>';
   $e = $e + 3;
 }
```

Alternatively, use modulo, something like

```
if ($i % 3 == 0)
```

Comment: Perfect!  That did the trick.  Thank you for the quick response, I can move on.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update $e when $i == $e. That condition is already being used in your if statement. Just add

```
$e += 3;
```

and you are done.

```
if ($i == $e){
   echo '<tr>';
   $e += 3;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You know when you get so close to something, you can't see the answer even when it's obvious after the fact... Thanks man,